# How to commit manually added files into git through terminal?

Tags: git

I had cloned a folder form git and manually added a file into it. How to add, commit and push the manually added file?

I have tried the commands:

```
    git add .
    git commit -m "__________"
    git push -u
```

It failed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Define "failed". _How?_

Comment: Changes not staged for commit:
         modified:   BinaryTree (modified content)

        no changes added to commit. This is the error message it got.

Answer (score 0):

have you set remote `git remote add remotname git@github.com`.

try `git remote -v` if you want to know remote defined in your project directory.

check [this](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)

hope well :)

Comment: How could I get the remotename?

Comment: `git remote -v` to showing remote lists have been set.

Answer (score 0):

First, perform a pull operation to pull all the changes from the git remote repo
`git pull 'github repo link'`

Add all the files to git remote repo
`git add .`

Commit the changes with a message
`git commit -m 'commit message'`

Push the changes to remote repo
`git push -u origin master`